# "kendo-switch" change height, width and color

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to change the height, width and color of the "kendo-switch". 
I tried to change the style of the element but that didn't work.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Let's see what you tried

Comment: the basic: style="width:10px"

Answer (score 3):

To change height and width override .k-switch class and change font size:

```
.k-switch {
    font-size: 5px !important;
}
```

To change background color of switch override .k-switch-on and .k-switch-off classes

```
.k-switch-on  {
    background-color: green !important;
}
.k-switch-off  {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

To remove text:

```
<kendo-switch [onLabel]="' '" [offLabel]="' '"></kendo-switch>
```

To change circle ON color:

```
.k-switch-handle{
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried to change the color with your solution and i don't know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the height use:

```
.k-switch {
  font-size: 7px;
}
```

For the width you can use:

```
.k-switch {
  width: 100px;
}
```

For the "On" color you can use:

```
.k-switch-on .k-switch-handle {
  background-color: mediumseagreen !important;
}

.k-switch-on .k-switch-container {
  background-color: palegreen !important;
}
```

For the "Off" color:

```
.k-switch-off .k-switch-handle {
  background-color: red !important;
  background-image: none !important; /*Not sure if this is always required*/
}

.k-switch-off .k-switch-container {
  background-color: tomato !important;
}
```

Also, to add a nice highlighted hover effect, add this:

```
.k-switch *:hover {
  filter: brightness(110%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom configurations from the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/switch/appearance):

**Size**

The size option controls how big or small the switch looks. The structure of the class is k-switch-{size}.

The following values are available for the size option:
sm — small size,
md — medium size,
lg — large size,
none — unset:

```
<input id="switch" />
<script>
    $("#switch").kendoSwitch({
        size:"large"
    })
</script>
```

For a live example, visit the [Appearance Demo of the Switch.](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/switch/appearance)